# Adding two different COUNTIF formulas

Tags: countif

How can I add two different COUNTIF formulas that look at different criteria. For example:

Column A shows me dates `4/1/2013`
Column B shows me the Type of product `HQTT`

I plug this formula in:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,M3)+COUNTIF(B:B,"HQ TT")
```

However this gives me `2` when it should be `1` because I only have one row that says `4/1/2013` with the product `HQTT`.

Comment: 1 [countif] tag is a bit vague - is this in Excel?

Comment: Can you provide the spreadsheet?

Comment: Um How do I add the spreadsheet?

Comment: @PeteGO? I am not sure how to add the spreadsheet on here? I feel weird asking lol

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is saying:

Count all the '4/1/2013' values in column A.

Count all the 'HQ TT' values in column B.

Give me the sum of these 2 counts.

I think what you want is a 3rd column, `=A&B` and a formula on that `=COUNTIF(C:C,M3&"HQ TT")`

Comment: so basically what I need is a formula that will count them both but give me one total so if the date 4/1/2013 and "HQ TT" is listen 10 times it gives me the total as 10 and not 20? Does that make sense? Im just not sure if there is a formula that can do that on Excel?

Comment: Yes I think so.  Does my answer not give you what you need then?

Comment: No, but I got it! Thank you! I used this formula =COUNTIFS(A:A,Q37,B:B,"HQ TT") and Im getting the results I need. Thank you so much though! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, per OP:

> I used this formula
>            `=COUNTIFS(A:A,Q37,B:B,"HQ TT")`
>   and Im getting the results I need.